# Distributed Load Testing in Visual Studio Ultimate 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, load-testing

All of the load tests documentation on MSDN describes a computer (running visual studio) connecting to a test controller, which connects to the test agents. Is it possible to run Visual Studio on the Test Controller, and run tests from there?

Comment: For up to about 250 virtual users you can run a load test directly from Visual Studio without needing controllers or agents. For bigger tests Visual Studio can be the controller and use agents.

Answer (score 0):

Running Visual Studio on a Controller with agents is more or less like running local test. You can run load tests from a single (developer?) machine, but you usually can't generate enough traffic to really see how the application responds, especially if the target is hosted on the same machine. It's also very depending on your context.

Using Controllers & Agents in a test rig, provides a distributed architecture to generate a lot of load and activity.